# Why does my date variable reset in my map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/challenge-of-building-a-calendar-with-pure-javascript-a86f1303267d) on making a javascript calendar and trying to implement it in react

The working javascript version is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45xdqu62/)

```
import { useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'

const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
// console.log('render')

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const today = new Date()
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(today.getMonth())
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(today.getFullYear())
  const calendarBodyRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const rows = 6
  const cells = 7
  const firstDay = (new Date(currentYear, currentMonth)).getDay()

  // check how many days in a month code from https://dzone.com/articles/determining-number-days-month
  const daysInMonth = (iMonth: number, iYear: number) => {
    return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Calendar Budget App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.calendarWrap}>
        <h2 className={styles.monthTitle}>{months[currentMonth]} {currentYear}</h2>
        <div className={styles.daysWrap}>
          <span>Sun</span>
          <span>Mon</span>
          <span>Tue</span>
          <span>Wed</span>
          <span>Thu</span>
          <span>Fri</span>
          <span>Sat</span>
        </div>
        <div ref={calendarBodyRef} className={styles.calendarBody}>
          {[...Array(rows).keys()].map((row) => {
            let date = 1
            return (
              <div key={row} className={styles.row}>
                {[...Array(cells).keys()].map((cell) => {
                  if (row === 0 && cell < firstDay) {
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}></div>
                    )
                  } else if (date > daysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear)) {
                    return
                  } else {
                    const cellText = String(date)
                    date++
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}>{cellText}</div>
                    )
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

However, after my `date` variable increments in the `else` statement, I reset my count back to `1` at the end of every row.

[image]

How do I stop resetting my `date` variable back to `1` at the end of every row?

Comment: Are you initializing the date in the correct place? `let date = 1` happens for every row, as it's inside the row loop.

Comment: don't initialize date inside of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite happy with the accepted answer and its discussion, so here comes a rather lengthy answer to provide some additional context. I hope it might be helpful, if not then that's tough luck, I guess.

---

Logically, your problem is that you initialize your variable inside the `[...Array(rows).keys()].map` callback (`let date = 1`). Moving the initialization outside the loop will fix this logical problem.

Syntactically, you can't just move it outside of the `map` call, because you're using JSX, [which just provides syntactic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for a `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` call. While your `map` call returns an array of JSX elements, and hence a valid argument for `children`, a variable declaration using `let` in its place will lead to a syntax error.

Extracting your rendering logic to a separate function in order to move the initialization before the loop, as shown by other answers, addresses this problem. Importantly, however, it does **not extract the same logic** but enables you to slightly change your logic (by moving the initialization outside of the loop). Also, the new function is not absolutely necessary, other *syntactical hacks* let you achieve the same thing, e.g.:

```
<div key={row} className={styles.row}>
  {[0].map((e) => {
    let date = 1;
    return [...Array(cells).keys()].map((cell) => {
      if (row === 0 && cell < firstDay) {
        return <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}></div>;
      } else if (date > daysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear)) {
        return;
      } else {
        const cellText = String(date);
        date++;
        return (
          <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}>
            {cellText}
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  })}
</div>;
```

I believe in your case, you could even just move the initialization to the top of your component.

---

The situation you ended up in is one of callback functions with side effects (the `date` declared outside the callback is changed from within the callback), which often negatively impacts readability and maintainability of your code. JSX works well with a declarative approach and [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (as your use of `map` shows).

Below an example of how you could achieve your goal by calculating number of the day without side effects.

To calculate which number to display in each cell, it relies on the cell index and factors in the offset of the specific month. The indexes used for the calculations of are provided by `map` as the second parameter to the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters). Step by step:

1. It calculates the days processed before the current week, derived from the current `weekIndex`
2. To that it adds the number days processed in the current week, derived from the current `dayIndex`
3. To that it adds `+1` to arrive at the 1-based cell index. This is required because `dayIndex` (like all indexes in JavaScript) is 0-based.
4. The 1-based cell index is only the correct day number if the first day of the month fell on a Sunday (`offset` = 0). Therefore, the calculation factors in the offset of this month.

The result is a concise function with an inexpensive calculation:

```
const calculateDay = (weekIndex, dayIndex, offset) =>
        7 * weekIndex + dayIndex + 1 - offset;

// Friday April 1 : 7 * 0 + 5 + 1 - 5 = 1
// Monday April 11: 7 * 2 + 1 + 1 - 5 = 11
// Sunday May 1   : 7 * 0 + 0 + 1 - 0 = 1
// Tuesday May 31 : 7 * 4 + 2 + 1 - 0 = 31
```

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(today.getMonth());
  const currentYear = today.getFullYear();
  
  const months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];
  const weekDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

  const daysInMonth = (iMonth, iYear) => {
    return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate();
  };

  const calculateDay = (weekIndex, dayIndex, offset) =>
    7 * weekIndex + dayIndex + 1 - offset;

  const renderCalendar = () => {
    const totalDays = daysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear);
    const firstDayInMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth).getDay();
    const totalWeeks = Math.ceil((firstDayInMonth+totalDays) / 7);

    return (
      <div className="table">
        <div className="row">
          {weekDays.map((e) => (
            <div className="column" key={`col${e}`}>
              {e}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {[...Array(totalWeeks)].map((w, wIx) => {
          return (
            <div className="row">
              {weekDays.map((d, dIx) => (
                <div className="column">
                  {(wIx === 0 && dIx < firstDayInMonth) ||
                  calculateDay(wIx, dIx, firstDayInMonth) > totalDays
                    ? ""
                    : calculateDay(wIx, dIx, firstDayInMonth)}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Calendar Budget App</h1>
      <div>
        <select
          value={currentMonth}
          onChange={(e) => setCurrentMonth(e.target.value)}
        >
          {months.map((m, i) => (
            <option value={i}>{m}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <h2>
          {months[currentMonth]} {currentYear}
        </h2>
        {renderCalendar()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <App / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  margin: 48px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #cfcfcf;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  min-height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.row:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain how your `calculateDay` function works in a little more detail?

Comment: Updated my answer with a simplified `calculateDay` and added the related explanations

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer, extract your print into another function and call it with your component's return statement.
Also note that your print statement is O(n^2) so re-rendering with be a costly operation.

Code:

```js
import { useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'

const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
// console.log('render')

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const today = new Date()
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(today.getMonth())
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(today.getFullYear())
  const calendarBodyRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const rows = 6
  const cells = 7
  const firstDay = (new Date(currentYear, currentMonth)).getDay()

  // check how many days in a month code from https://dzone.com/articles/determining-number-days-month
  const daysInMonth = (iMonth: number, iYear: number) => {
    return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate()
  }

  const renderCalendar = () => {
            let date = 1;
            return [...Array(rows).keys()].map((row) => {
            return (
              <div key={row} className={styles.row}>
                {[...Array(cells).keys()].map((cell) => {
                  if (row === 0 && cell < firstDay) {
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}></div>
                    )
                  } else if (date > daysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear)) {
                    return
                  } else {
                    const cellText = String(date)
                    date++
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}>{cellText}</div>
                    )
                  }
                })}
 </div>
            )
          })}
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Calendar Budget App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.calendarWrap}>
        <h2 className={styles.monthTitle}>{months[currentMonth]} {currentYear}</h2>
        <div className={styles.daysWrap}>
          <span>Sun</span>
          <span>Mon</span>
          <span>Tue</span>
          <span>Wed</span>
          <span>Thu</span>
          <span>Fri</span>
          <span>Sat</span>
        </div>
        <div ref={calendarBodyRef} className={styles.calendarBody}>
          {renderCalendar()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Why does extracting the logic into another function work instead of just putting the logic directly in the html?

Comment: cause it allows you to initialize the date varaible outside of the array methods i.e. outside of the  `map` function

Answer (score 0):

I like michmich112's answer but unfortunatly I can't comment on it (lack of reputation)

But you can improve the render time by adding useMemo

```
import { useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'

const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
// console.log('render')

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const today = new Date()
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(today.getMonth())
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(today.getFullYear())
  const calendarBodyRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const rows = 6
  const cells = 7
  const firstDay = (new Date(currentYear, currentMonth)).getDay()

  // check how many days in a month code from https://dzone.com/articles/determining-number-days-month
  const daysInMonth = (iMonth: number, iYear: number) => {
    return 32 - new Date(iYear, iMonth, 32).getDate()
  }

  const renderCalendar = useMemo(() => {
            let date = 1;
            return [...Array(rows).keys()].map((row) => {
            return (
              <div key={row} className={styles.row}>
                {[...Array(cells).keys()].map((cell) => {
                  if (row === 0 && cell < firstDay) {
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}></div>
                    )
                  } else if (date > daysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear)) {
                    return
                  } else {
                    const cellText = String(date)
                    date++
                    return (
                      <div key={cell} className={styles.cell}>{cellText}</div>
                    )
                  }
                })}
 </div>
            )
          })}
  }, [currentMonth, currentYear])

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Calendar Budget App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.calendarWrap}>
        <h2 className={styles.monthTitle}>{months[currentMonth]} {currentYear}</h2>
        <div className={styles.daysWrap}>
          <span>Sun</span>
          <span>Mon</span>
          <span>Tue</span>
          <span>Wed</span>
          <span>Thu</span>
          <span>Fri</span>
          <span>Sat</span>
        </div>
        <div ref={calendarBodyRef} className={styles.calendarBody}>
          {renderCalendar()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```